# Getting 'File to import not found or unreadable' when running sass

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I'm using gulp-ruby-sass and here's the code in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass('styles/app.scss', { style: 'expanded'})
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.message);
        })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

When I run gulp styles, I get the error

```
gulp-ruby-sass stderr: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: vendor/normalize-scss/_normalize.scss.
        on line 1 of styles/app.scss
```

Sass is at version 3.4.14, compass at 1.0.3, gem at 2.0.14

I have referred to several posts and none of them were able to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you share your sass code? It seems to be a problem with the path of your vendor file.

Comment: In app.scss, I changed the path of the file to be relative and it worked i.e. the vendor directory is located in parallel with styles directory. Making the path relative worked. However, the same code was working fine earlier.